# Error while running API :Undefined Property

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

Magento 2.3, here is the stack trace:

> rk/App/ErrorHandler.php:61)"} []
>   var//log/exception.log:[2019-12-12 07:26:41] main.CRITICAL: Report ID: webapi-5df1ebb139956; Message: Notice: Undefined property: SimplifiedMagento\Custom2\Model\OrderedRepository::$OrderedInterface in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Magento2_3/app/code/SimplifiedMagento/Custom2/Model/OrderedRepository.php on line 77

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined $orderedInterface variable wrong in SimplifiedMagento/Custom2/Model/OrderedRepository.php.(Maybe Spelling Mistake/lower or upper case of veriable)

Comment: Thanks developer........it worked somehow